# Issue with flutter and google maps widgets

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm really novice in flutter and i encounter an issue with google maps widget. I tried to follow the tutorial of medium: https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245

Unfortunately, when i'm running the app i have a blank image.
**Screenshot of the app**

[image]

Does somebody have ever encountered this problem ? Do you have a suggestion in which direction i can try to investigate?

Comment: Post your code, and are you using a valid API key?

Answer (score 0):

Your API key is invalid. Or you haven't turned on Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

The map feature showing up without maps is a clear question about your google map setup in Flutter. Make sure you have the following configurations.

**Get an API Key** at [cloud.google.com/maps-platform/](http://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) and make sure to select the right map features you want. If you are not sure, select them all.

**In Android:**
Specify your API key in the application manifest android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

**Next:** Go to Android manifest and insert the meta-data needed to attached your google maps account to the Flutter App.

Make sure you add your API-Key where it shows in the code.

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

**Then:** go into your iOS setting in ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m add add the required google codes.

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

Additional information can be found within the Dart package [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/)